# Showing data in Bootstrap list-group in Django template

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap, django-templates

I have data of cars and I want them to be shown in Bootstraps list-group. Problem is that I want one car brand to be shown **only once.**

```
{u'cars': [{u'brand': u'Ford', u'model': u'Focus'}, {u'brand': u'u'Ford', u'model': u'Fiesta'}, {u'brand': u'u'Toyota', u'model': u'Hilux'}]
```

I append to list cars in views.py:

```
for i in readable_json["cars"]:
            cars.append({
                'brand': i['brand'],
                'model': i['model'],
               })
```

So, in this example I want that is shown like this in Bootstrap list-groups: http://www.bootply.com/XEnAquIInD

NOT LIKE THIS:
http://www.bootply.com/2YX7PgB1ch

The problem comes to me in Django templates. I need to have different data-parent ID in HTML for the list-items, when I loop the cars in template. Also, how I can check, that there is not more than once one car brand shown?

```
<div id="MainMenu">
        <div class="list-group panel">
          <div href="#demo" class="list-group-item list-group-item-success"  data-parent="#MainMenu">Laitteet</div>
          <div class="collapse in" id="demo">

          {% for car in cars %}

          <a href="#{{ ??? }}" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#{{ ??? }}">{{ car.brand }} <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>

            <div class="collapse list-group-submenu" id="{{ ??? }}">
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#{{ ??? }}">{{ car.model }}</a>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should not be doing logic like checking uniqueness in the template - you need to do that in your view and filter the data before it is passed to the template. Adding a unique ID then becomes simple.

Comment: Should I do then two lists; one for cars and one for ID:s?

Comment: No. It partly depends where your data is coming from - does it have a unique ID at source (e.g., database ID?). If not, you could [slugify](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/utils/#django.utils.text.slugify) a unique field like the car name.

Comment: That's seems good. Still I can't figure out how I should get the data from view to the template in such form that I can get it in list right.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this to clean up the data in your view:

```
cars_seen = set()
for i in readable_json["cars"]:
    car_identifier = '{}-{}'.format(i['brand'], i['model'])
    if not car_identifier in cars_seen:
        cars.append({
            'brand': i['brand'],
            'model': i['model'],
            'id': car_identifier,
        })
    cars_seen.add(car_identifier)
```

`cars` will now contain a list of unique cars (assuming `brand` + `model` is how you define uniqueness).

In the template, you could then generate unique IDs with something like:

```
<a href="#{{ car.car_identifier|slugify }}">...</a>
```

Comment: Still the cars list could have multiple times same brand names like this: http://www.bootply.com/2YX7PgB1ch , so the identifier isn't working as should.

Comment: Yes - if you follow my code it accounts for that. You aren't going to get an off-the-shelf solution here and need to understand the underlying logic so that you can implement it yourself.